# how to give space or margin between image and text

Tags: css

I have a header in which I have one **<** image and **back** text is present .I need to give space or margin between these field **example :5px** .can we give margin in between field .
here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGgXVE

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<ion-view>
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
        <div class="buttons">
           <a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear">Back</a>
          <!--i style="font-size:30px;" class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i-->
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>


</ion-view>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.button:before{
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

The `:before` element is the `<` icon.